# Not able to copy original top command executable over a malicious one

Tags: permissions, malware

Somebody hacked my system and replaced some of the system commands like top, ps, find etc with malicious ones.

Now, I am trying to copy the original ones, but the copy or move commands fail, even though I am logged in as root user.

I get the following error:

```
cp /root/top /usr/bin/
cp: overwrite `/usr/bin/top', overriding mode 0755? y
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/bin/top': Permission denied
```

Can somebody please tell me a way by which I can copy my original files.

Comment: Actually I cannot re-install the OS in short time, its a server used by different groups, so it will at least take a week to update all the guys and to arrange a backup.So, it will be really helpful If you can please suggest a temporary fix until new OS is installed

Answer (score 4):

The directory may have been made read-only, or maybe a file has been made immutable through extended attributes. But I'll deliberately not tell you how to fix that, because that's not the right way to proceed. When a machine has been infected by malware, you can't know what is wrong. There's a good chance that the kernel is infected too, and that any fix you attempt will only appear to succeed.

[**Nuke it from orbit.**](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30091/best-practices-for-handling-computer-viruses/30097#30097) In other words, throw away the existing installation and reinstall the system from scratch. You'll want to copy the **data**. Ideally, restore it from a known good backup. If you don't have a full good backup, restore from the latest good backup and carefully copy more recent files. But **you must reinstall the operating system**. Be sure to wipe the existing kernel and system installation, to avoid accidentally keeping infected files around. Better, install to a new disk, keeping the old one around (without ever *running* anything from it) to figure out what happened so that it doesn't happen again.

Comment: actually I cannot re-install the OS in short time, its a server used by different groups, so it will at least take a week to update all the guys and to arrange a backup.So, it will be really helpful If you can please suggest a temporary fix until new OS is installed. Thx

Comment: @user42238 Then you might as well do nothing. If the malware isn't a critical problem for you, don't remove it. If it is a problem, remove it. There are no half measures.

Comment: Thanks, I fully agree with you that OS installation is the best step. The problem is we need to run top, ps and netstat utilities to monitor this server and all these are affected by this malware due to which results reported by the commands are inaccurate, like top reports 95% CPU is being used, but in actually only 5% is being used, so I want to first fix these commands output, until we are ale to re-install. As one of the temp fixes, I have aliased command paths to original executable. But it will be good if I can copy them at standard paths.